# Detecting modfications in the persistent state

Tags: hibernate, orm

I know that during a update hibernate cand detect if any change has been done.
If it is no, no sql request will be done.

IS there a way to get this boolean information  computed by hibernate ?

Thanks in advance 
Regards

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean [`Session.isDirty()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#isDirty())?